# Android RecyclerView - implement Drag and Drop without rearranging of elements

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop

I need to implement drag and drop in RecyclerView. But I do not want to rearrange item orders while dragging. I want rather dragging content from one item to another item. Like in standard Drag And Drop.

1. I long press on item
2. Then I modify content of dragged item (ex. change background colour)
3. Then I show preview of dragged item (like previously in my item)
4. Then move this preview of content around recyclerview and also between scrollable pages (with snaphalper)
5. Then drop this preview on another item, if so. content from previous item is copied into new item.

My recyclerView should be like checkers game, where items grid is placeholder for draggable content (like pawns).